# TYPO3 - How to hook into Extbase argument mapping mechanism?

Tags: typo3, extbase, datamapper

How can I hook into Extbase argument mapping mechanism? I want to be able to use regular controller arguments like…

```
MyController::showAction(MyModel $myModel)
```

…although $myModel is not a database based object. It is just transient, delivered by a foreign API. Where can I hook into to manually build the object? Or how to tell the DataHandler that when an integer value „5“ is passed to this showAction(), it should ask my custom (api) service to retrieve the correct record an build the „MyModel“ object from it?

The question is not about how to retrieve the data from the foreign API or how to convert it to a local domain model in general. It is just about how to hook into the „magic“ object mapping mechanism.

Comment: IMO Daniel's Blogpost "Data Transfer Objects in Extbase" should give you some hints: https://usetypo3.com/dtos-in-extbase.html

Comment: Not really. As I said the question is NOT about HOW to convert external data to models. I just want to know about where the automatic object mapping mechanism takes place and how to hook into or extend it by own logic. But thanks despite.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I have combined two posts in my thought, but have linked the wrong one.  This magic is done via PropertyMapper, which can be influenced via `initialize*Action()`-methods. Stefan has written (a german) post about it: https://www.typo3lexikon.de/typo3-tutorials/core/systemextensions/extbase/property-mapper.html

Comment: @JulianHofmann Ah, thx! That's what I’ve already thought, too. Will try this way… Do you think this (initialize*Action()) is the deepest level to accomplish this? Does Extbase do it in the similar way or place in behind?